# How can I pass more than one field to a search function? In Odoo 9

Tags: python, filter, odoo, odoo-9

I want to set a domain for a field in a view.

```xml
<record id="view_pack_operation_details_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">stock.pack.operation.details.form.extend</field>
  <field name="model">stock.pack.operation</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_pack_operation_details_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='location_dest_id']" position="replace">            
      <field name="show_all_locations_checkbox"/>
      <field name="location_dest_id" domain="[('is_empty', '=', picking_destination_location_id)]"/>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

I have created a search function, but it only accepts one operand.

```py
is_empty = fields.Boolean(compute='compute_is_empty', search='search_is_empty')


def search_is_empty(self, operator, operand):
    ids = []

    # I need here the value of show_all_locations_checkbox
    show_all_locations = VALUE_OF_CHECKBOX
    locations = self.env['stock.location'].search([('location_id', '=', operand)])
    for location in locations:
        stock_quant = len(self.env['stock.quant'].search([('location_id', '=', location.id)]))
        if show_all_locations:
            ids.append(location.id)
        else:
            if stock_quant == 0:
                ids.append(location.id)

    return [('id', 'in', ids)]
```

Is there any option to pass more than one field in domain operand?

Comment: not really, but you can play with the data type you pass. For example, instead of passing a field you can pass a dictionary/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass more than one operand, but you can play with the data type you pass. For example, instead of passing a field, you can pass a dictionary/list.